# Kotlin generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

How is it possible to enforce a generic type for a method in Kotlin?
I know for instance you can do the following:

```
var someVar: MutableSet<out SomeType> = hashSetOf()
```

How can you do the same for a method?

```
fun <T> doSomething() {
}
```

I'd like to enforce `T` to be of type `X` or a sub-type of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After googling around, the correct answer would be:

```
fun <T : X> doSomething() {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually `out SomeType` means more than "type Parameter can be SomeType or any of its subtypes" as your questions suggests.

The keyword `out` is Kotlin's way to say that, in this example, the `MutableSet` is a *Producer* of `SomeType`, i.e.  it is **covariant** in its type parameter. As a consequence you will not be able to call methods like `add(t:T)`, but only those which return `T`s, like `get():T`.

Back to your question: if your method is supposed to accept types of `X` or its subtypes, you should use "bounds":

```
fun <T : X> doSomething() {
}
```

This is just what you need, but to make it clear again, it cannot be said to be the equivalent to your other example.

Answer (score 2):

as @s1m0nw1 quoted, you can use 

`fun <T : X> doSomething() {
}`

to limit T subtype of X,

additional, you can use 

`fun <T> doSomething where T : Comparable, T : Cloneable {
}`

to limit T should implement both `Comparable` and `Cloneable`

as referenced here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html